# Unable to add references on VS code C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-code, .net-core, reference

Please I started learning C# doing tutorials on youtube. At some point, I had to add reference from class library but it still says "The name does not exist in current context". Pls any ideas on what could be the issue? Thanks

Trying to add the TrackerLibrary reference as shown

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Pls ensure you have added the reference to your project (via nugget or dll...) and also a using directive may be missing in the code.

Comment: @David Thanks. I'm pretty new to the language; was following a tutorial accordingly and encountered this, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Hi Greg. 
You should use a using directive to include these classes into your code and then you can reference them. 
Add this using to your code and tell me.

"using TournamentTracker.TrackerLibrary; "

Comment: Thanks David. Tried it but it says "the namespace name TournamentTracker could not be found".

Comment: Hi. This is because you must add a reference into the project.
Right click at the project TrackerUI and use add reference from the project to include the TrackerLibrary. After this the using should not give you an error.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue I have. Already did that and I get "The name does not exist in current context". Don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240670/discussion-between-david-and-greg616).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your TrackerUI project and click Add-> Project Reference and a list will be displayed.

From the list select TrackerLibrary and add it to your project.